# Azure Custom Domain not resolving

Tags: azure, cname

It seems like I have my A CNAME and TXT records correct for my Azure App but My Domain name is still not resolving.
Error:
404 Web Site not found.

You may be seeing this error due to one of the reasons listed below :

```
Custom domain has not been configured inside Azure. See how to map an existing domain to resolve this.
Client cache is still pointing the domain to old IP address. Clear the cache by running the command ipconfig/flushdns.
```

Here is my source tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting that message, you probably haven't configured the domain as a Custom Domain.

In Portal go to the App > Custom Domain and make sure it's there.

If you do have it added, it's possible the A record is pointing to the wrong IP. You can check if it matches the one in the Custom Domain blade by running the following command in your command line:

```
nslookup <your domain>
```

Comment: Thank you @ardoRic, yes I used the Custom Domain IP when creating the A record. 23.99.206.151
`Server:  68.105.28.11
Address: 68.105.28.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: emissions.watch
Address: 23.99.206.151`

The address below the domain seems correct.

Comment: would you mind sharing what is your web app name? the default address with the azurewebsites.net domain?

Comment: from what I can see it's configured correctly. the ip address of markstest1 and emissions.watch match.

If you're seeing the emissions.watch domain in Custom Domains, I would try to remove and add it back.

If it doesn't work, contact Azure Support because it should work. I suspect your TLD (watch) may be causing issues.

Comment: you don't need to buy the domain from Azure, but if you're using the Free tier of App Services you might need to upgrade it to Shared to use a Custom Domain with your app. According to [the pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/#pricing) the Free tier dos not support custom domains.

Comment: I'm on Pay As You Go but Ill check it for shared.