# Trouble mapping Godaddy Domain to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

Okay, I feel like I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

I have an website deployed to Azure App Service. Going to `<myapp>.azurewebsites.net` works fine.

I have a domain purchased by Godaddy.

Steps I've taken:

1. Added an A record to Godaddy with type "@" and value of the IP range identified in the Custom Domain section of my Azure App Service.
2. Added a CName with Name of "www" and value of `<myapp>.azurewebsites.net`.
3. Then, on Azure portal, to validate the Godaddy domain I went through the custom domain validation process, in which it says to add a TXT record with a name of "asuid" and provides a value. I added that to my Godaddy domain and clicked validate. I created the SSL binding. On my Azure portal, all shows green.

Yet when I go to https://www.myGodaddyDomain.com I get the blue screen:

```
404 Web Site not found.
You may be seeing this error due to one of the reasons listed below :

Custom domain has not been configured inside Azure. See how to map an existing domain to resolve this.
Client cache is still pointing the domain to old IP address. Clear the cache by running the command ipconfig/flushdns.
Checkout App Service Domain FAQ for more questions.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Refer the answers in these 2 posts for the similar error- 1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565321/azure-web-app-custom-domain-problem

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525071/azure-custom-domain-not-resolving. And this link- https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains.html

Comment: I read that but I just don’t know enough networking to know how to interpret it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***In your Azure Web app > Left Pane > Go to Settings > Custom domains > In right pane down > Add custom domain > Domain provider Select All other domain services > Keep TLS/SSL certificate > App Service Managed Certificate TLS/SSL type >SNI SSL, IP based SSL > In Domain tab below add your domain name > Example - siliconsidcloud.com > Hostname record type set to A record (example.com) > Domain validation section will open below:-***

[image]

[image]

In order for Azure to authenticate with our domain follow the steps below:-

Copy the A record like below:-

[image]

***Visit your go daddy > dcc.godaddy.com/manage/siliconsidcloud.com/dns > Click on A record > Edit button on right > in A record section > Type A , Name @ Value - Paste the copied IP address from A record above from Domain validation example- Value 20.118.40.3 > click on Save > Update a DNS record tab will open and DNS record will be updated.***

***Now Visit your Web app and TXT record*** like below:-

[image]

***Visit your go daddy > dcc.godaddy.com/manage/siliconsidcloud.com/dns > If you do not have TXT record in place click on Add from the right top > In Type choose TXT > In Name type asuid > In Value add the Copied value from above Azure TXT record> click on Add record***

***Now, Visit your Azure Portal and click on Validate*** like below:-

[image]

***After Validation passed message comes, If validation fails, Wait for 2-3 minutes and try again as it varies depending on the domain provider > Click on Add button the Custom Domain will be added > Adding Custom Domain and binding notification > custom domain will be added and marked as Secured > Now, Take the URL of your custom domain example - siliconsidcloud.com and browse your web app> the web app content will be available in your custom domain.***

---

> If you're using www in your Custom Domain > Add the
> **[www.siliconcloudsid.com](http://www.siliconcloudsid.com)** in the domain section
> OR**
> ***.siliconcloudsid.com and create CNAME and TXT record like below in your Go daddy DNS settings**

Add [www.siliconsidcloud.com](http://www.siliconsidcloud.com) or *.siliconsidcloud.com in the Domain tab and try to register the Custom domain with both and check which works.

Refer below image from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain#update-the-dns-record):-

> [image]

***After validation succeeds and while adding the domain if you receive No binding warning > If you selected Add certificate later > make sure you add your private certificate by referring this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex,portal) and binding by referring this [**Document2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings)*** ***If you select App service Managed Certificate the No binding error won't come.***

Additionally, You can run this command in your local Laptops Window terminal like below:-

```
ipconfig/flushdns
```

**Local:-**

[image]

**And run the below command in your Web app console to check the DNS resolution:-**

```bash
nslookup www.siliconsidcloud.com
```

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Azure web app custom domain problem - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565321/azure-web-app-custom-domain-problem) By Ryan Hill

[cname - Azure Custom Domain not resolving - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525071/azure-custom-domain-not-resolving) By ardoRic

[FAQ App Service Domain and Custom Domains - Azure App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains.html)